# Why does Android allow me to access a resource in an Activity before it is seen on the screen or loaded properly?

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have a rather weird problem and I am not sure how to search for it, I have searched and found very little.

So what happens is I have a bunch of Activities and each of them have a next button which will take me to the next Activity, each of these next buttons sit in the exact same place in each Activity.

So what happens is sometime the screen of my device is overly sensitive (an issue which we are sorting out) and other times it is normal. Either way the problem can be created, so what happens is when I press the next button and I sort of spam it or the screen double clicks in a sense then it would navigate from Activity 1 to Activity 3, this happens before I can even see Activity 2 on the screen. Again this is due to the next button sitting in the same place in Activity 1 and 2, so it is as if that element is already there and accessible before I see anything on the screen.

I have put code in to first check if the EditTexts in Activity 2 are empty and thus will not allow you to continue but even this is bypassed, it is as if this resource is already loaded into that location and its code gets executed before any other logic or Activity elements are created.

Has anyone else experienced this or know why this is happening? I have tried to make the button invisible until onCreate() has been called where I make it visible again, I have tried disabling the button and then enabling it in onCreate(), none of which works.

I can take a video to show this happening if it will make things more clear?

Thanks,
Wihan

Comment: I would initialize the buttons as disabled from the XML, that way the layout will be loaded with a non-clickable button. You can add TextWatcher to any EditText to know when they are not empty

Comment: Thats impossible. Post your code.

Comment: I have done this, the button is disabled in the XML that I load, I then enable it in the onCreate() of the Activity. My code is so massive, posting it would take forever and be so big.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably related to the fact you are twice pressing the next button on Activity1 so it pushes you twice through Activities list and not getting pressed on Activity2.
You provide too few code to analyze more concrete.

Add i.e. some debug message on pressing the button telling you parent activity.

Comment: That´s what I was thinking too, no way the button in activity2 is pressed before onCreate or anything else, he mentioned that disabeling the button in a2 was doing nothing so the next click propably does not come from a2

Comment: I hear what you are saying, the problem is that the next button in Activity 1 goes to Activity 2 while the next button in Activity 2 goes to Activity 3. So there is no way that double pressing the button in Activity 1 can go to 3.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the device is registering multiple touch events which are not consumed, and passed directly to the next activity's views. If that is the case, I would try some other lifecycle callback rather than onCreate() to toggle visibility or enabled state. The user would always see your activity (and touch events would be dispacthed) only after onCreate() has completed execution.

You can overrride onResume() and enable your button (or set it visible) **after** calling super.onResume().

Or you could try doing it in **onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)**. This method is called by the framework with parameter hasFocus as true after your UI has been displayed on the screen (and hopefully all pending touch events have been dispatched by the system).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.Callback.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)

If it is indeed a case of touch events being sent to the next activity, then delaying the button's functionality till onWindowFocusChanged() has been called should work. If it doesn't, then you might have to use some sort of timer to activate the button a few seconds after onCreate() has been called (which would be quite a hack)